# переменная окружения в ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

Есть учебно-тренировочный проект topjava, который использует переменную окружения TOPJAVA_ROOT ( путь к корню проекта) для записи логов и чтения конфигов. Переменная прописана в etc/environment таким образом:

`TOPJAVA_ROOT=/home/sebastian/my_java_projects/topjava`

Если путь к корню хардкодить в проекте - все ок. Если использовать переменную - конфиги не видятся, а логи пишутся в новую папку с таким же именем topjava. Таким образом в папке с проектами получается две папки с одинаковым именем. Если в новую папку скинуть конфиги - все работает. Вопрос: что вообще происходит и что с этим делать?

фрагмент spring-mvc.xml с переменной:

`<property name="basenames" value="file:///#{systemEnvironment['TOPJAVA_ROOT']}/config/messages/app"/>`

фрагмент spring-mvc.xml с хардкодом(рабочий):

`<property name="basenames" value="file:///home/sebastian/my_java_projects/topjava/config/messages/app"/>`

содержимое папки с проектами:

`:~/my_java_projects$ ls -al
итого 36
drwxr-x---  6 sebastian sebastian  4096 апр 26 15:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 64 sebastian sebastian 16384 апр 26 14:00 ..
drwxrwxrwx  9 sebastian sebastian  4096 апр 26 14:58 topjava
drwxr-x---  3 sebastian sebastian  4096 апр 26 15:00 topjava`

Comment: пробел после "topjava"?

Comment: Ну да, когда серым подсвечено его видно). Спасибо, все заработало!